# First order diferential equation with two integrating factors can be solved by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Consider the diferential equation
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
if $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are integrating factors then the diferential equation can be solved by separation of variables.

I don’t know how to prove it, for now, I only have used the hypothesis, that is, we know that $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are integrating factors so the equations
$$f(x)M(x,y)dx+f(x)N(x,y)dy=0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(y)M(x,y)dx+g(y)N(x,y)dy=0
$$
are exact but then I don’t know how to continue. I don’t know if multiplying the diferential equation by both functions at the same time can be useful.

I also know that if a diferential equation can be solved by separation of variables then the equation is exact but this isn’t useful.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

With some careful application of definition and a lot of computation, we can prove the separability of an equation with integrating factors.

Consider an integrating factor depending only on $x$ (you gave it as $f(x)$). Then we can do as you said:

$$f(x)M(x,y)dx + f(x)N(x,y)dy = 0$$

Now by definition of exactness of the above equation (which is an assumption you gave), we have that:

$$\frac{\partial \left( f(x)M(x,y)\right)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \left( f(x)N(x,y)\right)}{\partial x}$$

Just differentiate this:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}M(x,y) + f(x)\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}N(x,y) + f(x)\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

However, since the integrating factor $f$ is only a variable of $x$, the term with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, leading us to this equation:

$$f(x)\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}N(x,y) + f(x)\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\frac{f(x)}{N(x,y)}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$$

Now a bit of logic here, if $f$ is an integrating factor depending only on $x$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} := \frac{df}{dx}$, and actually, $\frac{df}{dx}$ itself is only a function of $x$. This means that the RHS of the above equation is also only a function of $x$, i.e.

$$q(x) := -\frac{1}{N(x,y)}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$$

Therefore, we have transformed the original equation:

$$f(x)M(x,y)dx + f(x)N(x,y)dy = 0$$

into:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -f(x)q(x)$$

Using an entirely similar set of steps and reasoning for the case of $g(y)$, (i.e. $g(y)M(x,y)dx + g(y)N(x,y) = 0$), we obtain:

$$\frac{dg}{dy} = -g(y)p(y)$$

Where $p(y)$ is defined as:

$$p(y) := -\frac{1}{M(x,y)}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$$

This allows us to solve for integrating factors $f$ and $g$ directly through separation of variables, the solution of which are:

$$f(x) = \exp\left(- \int q(x)dx\right) \qquad  g(x) = \exp\left(- \int p(y)dy\right)$$

To complete this...

We can now easily find a general solution for the equation of the form:

$$k(x,y) = C_{0}$$

where $C_{0}$ is a constant and $k(x,y)$ satisfies:

$$\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial k}{\partial y}dy = 0$$

P.S. Feel free to correct me if there's a mistake in any step of my work!